# Difference between slack bot and app tokens

Tags: slack, slack-api

What's the difference between Slack bot and app tokens, not in terms who and how they are given to (I really don't care) but in terms of their respective usage power. On OAuth and Permission page they can be given equal permissions/scope - so which one should I use? Also, when I post a message with a bot token it appears to be from the "app" and when I use an "app/user token" - it comes from the app bot, is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: I had to re-create the app so that a user, app and a bot all have distinctive names. I couldn't find any reason to use app tokens anymore (maybe they were required when classic bots didn't have enough privileges). The app with a bot token talks on behalf of bot which is sitting not under  "Direct messages" but under "Apps" section what makes it real confusing who is who. Also, updating bot/app names in the workspace doesn't seem to have any effect to what user sees. I think Slack should consider open a public forum because it's docs are very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

On the "OAuth and Permissions" page, as you said, there are two tokens. Bot User token and OAuth User.
One starts with "xoxb-"; the other one starts with "xoxp-".

The main difference on them is the abilities they have.
If I give to both tokens the scope `chat:write` and then use them on the API `chat.postMessage`, there's a difference. Bot tokens will post the message **as the app**, and you will see the message in the app's home tab. 
Instead, if you use the OAuth access token, the app **will impersonate you** (meaning another users won't be able to tell the difference between you and the app). This token also needs to be authorized by the user in question, otherwise you won't be able to use it

Comment: I hear what you're saying but in my opinion it would only be logical to make a parameter on who's behalf you want to post a message (a bot or yourself), not creating a whole parallel permission structure, big part of which doesn't even make a difference (e.g. reading user list, messages, user commands, etc)